# Find basis of the vector space $V=\left\{p(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]_4 \mid p^{\prime}(5)=0\right\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Trying to find basis for the following vector space $V=\left\{p(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]_4 \mid p^{\prime}(5)=0\right\}$

After calculating derivatives, I'm having $b = -10c - 75d - 500e - 3125f$ and thus the final basis looks like $B =({1,-10x+x^2,-75x+x^3,-500x+x^4,-3125x+x^5})$ and $dim(V)=5$. At the same time I'm not sure if the dimension for the basis will be correct. Am I missing something or it's fine?

Many thanks.

Comment: For $p(x)=a+bx+\dots\in\Bbb R_4[x],$ $f=0.$ Just delete the fifth vector of your $B$ and get $\dim(V)$ (not $W$) $=4.$ ($5$ would be impossible since in would imply $V=\Bbb R_4[x]$.)

Comment: clear, thank you very much